# from svn import core にて ImportError: DLL load failed: このオペレーティング システムでは %1 は実行されません。

Tags: windows, python

tortoisehg が提供している svn_1.7.5_py27_x86.zip  を site-packages 以下に展開し、
from svn import core にて ImportError が発生します。

https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg-winbuild/downloads/

```
c:\Python276>python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> from svn import core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python276\lib\site-packages\svn\core.py", line 26, in <module>
    from libsvn.core import *
  File "c:\Python276\lib\site-packages\libsvn\core.py", line 25, in <module>
    _core = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\Python276\lib\site-packages\libsvn\core.py", line 21, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_core', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: このオペレーティング システムでは %1 は実行されません。
>>>
>>>
```

環境は、Windows 8.1 Update の 64-bit 環境です。

32-bit 版だと発生し、64-bitのPythonではこのエラーは発生しません。

【再現手順】

1. Python 2.7.6 をインストールする (C:\Python276)
2. ダウンロードする https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg-winbuild/downloads/svn_1.7.5_py27_x86.zip
3. C:\Python276\Lib\site-packages 以下に展開する
4. python.exe を起動し from svn import core を実行する

Comment: 32bit版の svn_1.7.5_py27_x86.zip は試しましたか？

Comment: 32bit版の svn_1.7.5_py27_x86.zip を使いました（記述ミスでしたので直しました）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DLLの読み込みで失敗してそうなので、配布物のDLLの依存関係を調べてみました。

結局、 `libsvn_ra-1.dll` が `SSLEAY32.dll`<s>, `LIBEAY32.dll`</s>(小文字のファイル名で存在していました) を、 `libdb48.dll` が、 `MSVCP60.dll` を必要としてそうです。(そもそも配布物にあるものと標準にあるものは除いて、です)

で、手元の環境で同じような現象になったので [openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip) の bin 以下の二つの dll を libsvn 以下のものに上書きしたら例外は出なくなりました。

**ただ、バージョンが古いので、公開されるような場所でちゃんと使うなら[公式](https://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html)から安全なDLLを探すか、自分で作成する必要があるかもしれません。(この用途でどの脆弱性がどう影響してしまうかまでは見切っていません。)**

(以下、私が勘違いしてるかもしれないので、コマンドの結果を貼っておきます)

```
C:\temp> dumpbin.exe /DEPENDENTS libsvn_ra-1.dll libdb48.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file libsvn_ra-1.dll

File Type: DLL

  Image has the following dependencies:

    MSVCRT.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    libsvn_repos-1.dll
    libsvn_subr-1.dll
    LIBEAY32.dll
    SSLEAY32.dll
    libapr-1.dll
    libaprutil-1.dll
    Secur32.dll
    intl3_svn.dll
    WS2_32.dll
    libsasl.dll
    libsvn_delta-1.dll
    libsvn_fs-1.dll

Dump of file libdb48.dll

File Type: DLL

  Image has the following dependencies:

    WS2_32.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    ADVAPI32.dll
    MSVCRT.dll
    MSVCP60.dll

  Summary

       20000 .data
       19000 .rdata
        B000 .reloc
        4000 .rsrc
      15B000 .text
```

Comment: LIBEAY32.dll は配布物に含まれていますね。

Comment: うわ、小文字ありますね。。修正します。(というか答えがかぶってるので、もうすこし調べて良い回答が出てこなかったら消します、はい)

Comment: とりあえず、openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip に含まれるDLLの2つを置き換えるとエラーが解消することが確認できました

Comment: よかったです。 今回に関しては SSLEAY32.dll と LIBEAY32.dll のバージョン違いとかビルド環境の違いとかが原因っぽいですかね。。綺麗な気持ちで libsvn 以下を作ればよさそうです。(というか配布物に中途半端に入っているのはナゼ？)

Comment: ありがとうございます。原因がわかりました。配布物の内容が中途半端なことが真の原因と思います。Subversion1.7.5をインストールしたbin以下のssleay32.dllをlibsvn以下にコピーすることで問題が解決しました。

Answer (score 2):

エラー内容からは、なんらかの DLL の読み込みエラーとしかいえません。

今手元に Windows 環境がないので、試し様がないのですが・・・見当違いだったらご容赦を。`svn_1.7.5_py27_x86.zip` の中の `site-packages\libsvn` ディレクトリにある DLL をみてみると、

- SSLEAY32.DLL
- MSVCP60.DLL

が依存関係上必要で、このディレクトリにはありません。

ですので、これらのファイルが `site-packages\libsvn` の下もしくは、 `PATH` の通っている場所ににあるようしてください。 `MSVCP60.DLL` は、普通 `C:\Windows\System32` あたりにあるでしょう。

`SSLEAY32.DLL` がなければ、[ここから、OpenSSL をインストールすること](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html)で、もしくは、 `SSLEAY32.DLL` 自体を入手して `%PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR%\Lib\site-packages\libsvn`
に放り込んでください。（インストール時に、Dlls をどこに置くか聞いてきたならば、 `system32` へ放り込む）

そしてコンソールを閉じて、もしくは再起動して（念のため）再度トライ。

既にどちらのファイルも確認できるなら、エラーの原因としてまた別の理由を探さなければなりません。

Comment: MSVCP60.DLL はSystem32以下にありました。

SSLEAY32.DLLは無かったようなので、OpenSSLのインストール先(C:\OpenSSL-Win32)のbin以下にあったDLLを、libsvn以下にコピーしました。

しかし状況は変わりませんでした。

Comment: うーん、そうですか。。。お力添えになれずすみません。(今見てみたら、 SSLEAY32.DLL は、..._x64.zip の方にはあるんですね。なんだろう、もうすこし詳細なエラーが出ればなあ。)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。DependencyWalkerで足りないDLLを調べてみようとしたのですが、”応答なし状態”になってしまい、Pythonインタプリタが起動しない状態でなにが足りないか調べられませんでした。

Answer (score 2):

エラーはDLLに指定された序数がみつからないときに出るエラーです。 
インストールされているsvnのバージョンが1.7.5と異なるのではないでしょうか。

今、ほぼまっさらなWin8.1 pro(x64)に、python 2.7.6(x86)と質問に書いてあったsvn_1.7.5_py27_x86.zip、あとsvn 1.7.5をインストールしましたが、importエラーはなくなりました。

```
C:\Python276>python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from svn import core
>>>
```

---

```
C:\Python276>svn --version
svn, バージョン 1.7.5 (r1336830)
   コンパイル日時: May 11 2012, 13:51:05
```

python 2.7だったので、VC++2008のランタイムとVC++2008SP1のランタイムも入れてしまったのですが、
関係ないと思います（けど入れちゃったので報告はしておきます。）

ちなみにこのマシンにはtortoiseHgは入れてません。

---

## 追記

検証まではしていないのですが、こちらに各種バージョンのPython 2.7 bindingsがあります。
これを試してみる手もあるかもしれません。

http://alagazam.net/

alagazam.netですが、 [Apache Subversion Binary Packages (subversion.apache.org)](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html)の一番下の Win32Svnでも紹介されているサイトで、ダウンロードもSourceForge経由なので怪しいサイトではないと思います。

Comment: TortoiseSVN 1.8.8 をインストールした状態だったので一旦アンインストールしました。 TortoiseSVN 1.7.7 (SVN 1.7.5) をインストールしてみます。

Comment: 別のSVNのバージョン用のpython bindingについて追記しました。

Comment: 書き忘れましたが、私が入れたSVN1.7.5もalagazam.netのSVN 1.7.5のWindows Installerです。

Comment: TortoiseSVN 付属のCommandLine版(svn 1.7.5) を入れました。
しかし関係なかったようで、同じエラーが発生します。

Comment: 関係なかったというよりも、他のアプリケーションの問題が疑わしいです。どうやらSVNはインストール時にSubversionのbinを環境変数pathの最後に追加します。当然それより手前に問題のバージョン違いのモジュールを含むディレクトリがPATHにいたら改善はしないわけです。あとは配布モジュールが不完全なのではなく、SVNのモジュールを利用するようあえて含んでいない可能性があります。`C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin`を環境変数PATHの先頭に持ってきても上手くいくんじゃないかと。ちなみに「このオペレーティングシステムでは…」のエラーはDLLは見つかってるけど指定アドレスに関数がないというようなエラーです。（見つからない場合は「ImportError: DLL load failed:指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。」）。競合するなら今回とられたような近くに置いてあげる対処しかなさそうですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。もうひとつの解決方法がわかりました。ご指摘の通り、システム変数に自動で追加された```C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin```を先頭に持っていくと解決します。配布モジュールが不完全だと判断した理由は、x64の場合には該当するDLL(SSLEAY32.dll)が含まれているためx86の場合も同様に含めるべきだと考えました。

Comment: なるほど、64bitだと含まれているんですね。それなら不完全と考えて当然ですね。情報ありがとうございます。